# sql subquery from where in

Tags: sql, subquery, where-in

I'm writing something along these lines:

```
select fielda,fieldb,
       (select sum(field1)-sum(field2) as fieldc 
        from tableb 
        where fieldid = list_of_ids[i]) 
from tablea 
where fieldid in (list_of_ids);
```

In the subquery I'd like to use the value from the outer where clause. So if list_of_ids is 123,456,789 the fieldid in the subquery will be 123, the second 456, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: _Column_, not field...

Comment: Postgres, but Pelin's answer worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use  `ta.fieldid` instead of `list_of_ids[i]`

```
select ta.fielda,ta.fieldb,
       (select sum(tb.field1)-sum(tb.field2) as fieldc 
        from tableb tb
        where tb.fieldid = ta.fieldid ) 
from tablea  ta
where ta.fieldid in (list_of_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

A subquery is anchored to the individual record in the outer query.

```
select fielda,fieldb,
       (select sum(field1)-sum(field2) as fieldc 
        from tableb 
        where tableb.fieldid = tablea.fieldid) 
from tablea 
where tablea.fieldid in (list_of_ids);
```

By just using a simple comparison operator to correlate your subquery with your outer query, your subquery will compare against any fieldids found by the outer query as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
select ta.fielda,ta.fieldb,
       (select sum(field1)-sum(field2) as fieldc 
        from tableb tb
        where tb.fieldid = ta.fieldid ) 
from tablea  ta
where ta.fieldid in (list_of_ids);
```